# Bubble Sort By Moving Nodes in Linked List (C++)

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list, bubble-sort

I am doing bubble sort on linked list by comparing values in nodes and then moving nodes but there is a problem in my function. When i run my code it creates nodes fine but when **bubblesort()** function runs it throws an exception and it says "**p2 was nullptr**". I don't know what is wrong in my code and any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int number;
    Node* next;
};

class LinkedList {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
public:
    LinkedList() {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    void createnode(int num) {
        Node* temp = new Node;
        temp->number = num;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }
    void bubblesort(int size) {
        Node* temp;
        int i, j, swapped;
        for (i = 0; i <= size; i++){
            temp = head;
            swapped = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++){
                Node* p1 = temp;
                Node* p2 = p1->next;
                if (p1->number > p2->number){
                    Node* temp1 = p2->next;
                    p2->next = p1;
                    p1->next = temp1;
                    temp = p2;
                    swapped = 1;
                }
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (swapped == 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    void displaynodes() {
        Node* temp;
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->number << "  ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList l;
    int size, num;
    cout << "How many Numbers Do You Want to Store: ";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Enter Number " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> num;
        l.createnode(num);
    }
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Data Of Nodes Before Bubble Sort: " << endl;
    l.displaynodes();
    l.bubblesort(size);
    cout << "Data Of Nodes After Bubble Sort: " << endl;
    l.displaynodes();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Step through with your debugger! That should be your first step. Linked lists are tricky and monitoring the execution of the logic in real time is great for understanding what's happening. If you don't know how to use your debugger, what environment are you working in?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Alright I'll try debugging and i'm using visual studio.

Comment: If you don't know how to use your debugger, you want to `set a breakpoint` at the start of your problem code, and then `single step` through it. Observe your variables change in real time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many bad coding practice like `using namespace std;`, bad naming style and using `Null` instead of `nullptr`.

However the error was in the sorting snippet. You are trying to swapping the nodes but you can't do that without using the node previous to the current node or using doubly linked list. So in the following code, I swapped the numbers not the nodes.

```
void bubblesort(int size) {
    int i, j, swapped = 1;
    for (i = 0; swapped && i < size; i++){
        swapped = 0;
        Node* temp = head;
        for (j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++){

            if (temp->number > temp -> next ->number){
                int tempNumber = temp -> number;
                temp -> number = temp -> next -> number;
                temp -> next -> number = tempNumber;
                swapped = 1;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```